# Unexpected behaviour with AntiForgeryToken and ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, post, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I've started using AntiForgeryToken in some of my forms to prevent cross site request forgery. However I am getting some weird behaviour and just wanted to clarify whether this is a bug or just me doing something wrong. I am using the `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` call in my form. I then use the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute in the action method that the form posts to. I'm not using a salt at this point.

My understanding is that `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` generates a hidden input with a name of `__RequestVerificationToken` and a cookie named `__RequestVerificationToken_Lw__`, which should both contain the same value.

The behaviour I am experiencing however is that:

1. The cookie always has the same value no matter how many times you
   GET the page
2. The hidden input has a different value every time you GET the page
3. The ValidateAntiForgeryToken validates every time, even from a
   different site in a CSRF scenario.
4. If I change the value of the hidden input in the foreign site, the
   token doesn't validate (expected behaviour, but why does it validate
   when the hidden input/cookie value is different?)

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Ok, just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186253/why-is-antiforgerytokens-hidden-field-not-same-as-its-cookies-on-my-machine which states that they are serialized differently, hence they appear to contain different values. However this doesn't explain why my cookie value never changes (until I delete it and a new one is generated when I re-GET the page), yet the input value does change, or why it always validates.

Comment: This behaviour only seems to occur with secure requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For number 3, are you including the hidden field in your CSRF scenario?

The safety of the AntiForgeryToken is that the hidden input exists only in the page served by your domain, and cannot be copied or captured by another domain.  If you have mocked up a test which passes the hidden input, then that is not a valid test.

I suggest you read this article from Phil Haack:  [Anatomy of a Cross-site Request Forgery Attack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/02/anatomy-of-csrf-attack.aspx)

Comment: When I lifted the code as-is (with hidden form field) in the CSRF site, then submitted the form, it ALWAYS validated on the server. Obviously if the code is not there, it does not validate, as expected. Still do not know why the cookies value remains the same though.