# Why is there a difference in the validateantiforgerytoken cookie value and hidden form value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I have got the MVC4 `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute working perfectly. However, I don't understand what I am seeing in Fiddler. The cookie sent by the server to the browser is set to this value:

```
__RequestVerificationToken=FVcmfj07ZEuBdjGuqWu14KIzolxr0ArLgvbNdnq0c4DFywxSA31yIHbm2IzgTPMVhMl4STEh2re8oGmwsSjKtSBTolCsmyGGRnLE1qurUqA1
```

but the hidden form input is set to this value:

```
OxjO3NjS1ly-bqP9RnYK9Vx8ZJyLGVCuTQEuSCAQWofVmuJaRkEcnHAHWcDurXaH6DhUiZ6XY5wCgi70u19mPy9sydMrkuS9qlWMXxGL_401
```

i.e. they appear different where they should match. Am I not understanding cookies properly and perhaps the first string is not the actual 'value' of the cookie encrypted?

Comment: This is causing an error or is it working as expected and you don't understand why the values are different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is AntiForgeryToken's hidden field not same as its cookies on my machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186253/why-is-antiforgerytokens-hidden-field-not-same-as-its-cookies-on-my-machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](http://www.apress.com/9781430234043):

> The `__RequestVaerificationToken` hidden field contains a random component (matching the one in the cookie), but that's not all. If the user is logged in, then the hidden field value will also contain their user name (obtained from `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` and then encrypted).
>
> `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` checks that this matches the logged-in user. This adds protection in the unlikely scenario where an attacker can somehow write (but not read) cookies on your domain to a victim's browser and tries to reuse a token generated for a different user.