# Html Antiforgerytoken cookie and input values are different

Tags: c#, security, csrf

I am learning

> CSRF prevention techniques

and it is mentioned that

> Antiforgerytoken

is one of the ways to prevent it. In an ASP.NET MVC application we can use the **Html Helper** to add the token.

When I use fiddler I notice that the value of the token in the hidden form input tag and the value in the Cookie of the same name are different. Is this how it is supposed to be?

In that case how does the ASP.NET framework take care to find that the request is not forged.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: "[cookies and nonces]... is one of the ways to prevent it." - this is not exactly true. The bad guy will always likely to be able to get to the nonce or cookie. OWASP covers it on their CSRF page under [Prevention Measures That Do NOT Work](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). The only way to completely remediate is to challenge the user. That is, make the user re-authenticate on high value transaction.

Comment: OWASP only say do not use "a Secret Cookie". A token value that is submitted outside of the cookie mechanism is still the recommendation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a difference in the validateantiforgerytoken cookie value and hidden form value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911470/why-is-there-a-difference-in-the-validateantiforgerytoken-cookie-value-and-hidde)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is different set of data serialized to cookie (the "salt" and token) and to HTML markup (salt, token, creation time, username). They are different but still comparable.

Some more detailed explanation:

MVC's cookies have internal structure, so their serialized version looks different. The actual security token that is inside should be identical. The serializer stores different information, depending on what information is present (user identity name, etc.). There is also a version byte, an indicator whether this is a session cookie, etc.